# Get the text indie a tag from jsoup in an array

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using jsoup to parse the html elements

what i am doing is

```
 Elements e = document.select(".doc-type-list li a");
         System.out.println(e);
```

which is giving me this

```
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-d-topical.html">A &amp; D topical</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/a-d-cracked-skin-relief-cream.html">A + D Cracked Skin Relief cream</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-200-lice-treatment.html">A-200 Lice Treatment</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-25.html">A-25</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a-caro-25.html">A-Caro-25</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a-g-profen.html">A-G Profen</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-pro" href="/pro/a-hydrocort.html">A-Hydrocort</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-methapred-injection.html">A-Methapred injection</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a-methapred.html">A-Methapred</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/a-methapred-solution.html">A-methapred solution</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-pro" href="/pro/a-methapred-injection.html">A-Methapred Injection</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-phedrin.html">A-Phedrin</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/a-spaz.html">A-Spaz</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/a-tan-12x-suspension.html">A-Tan 12X suspension</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-e-r-witch-hazel.html">A.E.R. Witch Hazel</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a-b-otic.html">A / B Otic</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-fish-oil.html">A / Fish Oil</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/a-t-s.html">A / T / S</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a-t-s-topical.html">A / T / S Topical</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-monograph" href="/monograph/a1-proteinase-inhibitor-human.html">a1-Proteinase Inhibitor (Human)</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a200-maximum-strength-topical.html">A200 Maximum Strength Topical</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/a200-time-tested-formula-topical.html">A200 Time-Tested Formula Topical</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/abacavir.html">abacavir</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/abacavir.html">abacavir</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/abacavir-solution.html">abacavir solution</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/abacavir.html">abacavir</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-ppa" href="/ppa/abacavir.html">Abacavir</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/abacavir-and-lamivudine.html">abacavir and lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/abacavir-and-lamivudine.html">abacavir and lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-ppa" href="/ppa/abacavir-and-lamivudine.html">Abacavir and Lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-pro" href="/pro/abacavir-and-lamivudine-tablets.html">Abacavir and Lamivudine Tablets</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-monograph" href="/monograph/abacavir-sulfate.html">Abacavir Sulfate</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-pro" href="/pro/abacavir-sulfate-tablets.html">Abacavir Sulfate Tablets</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/abacavir-dolutegravir-and-lamivudine.html">abacavir, dolutegravir, and lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/abacavir-dolutegravir-and-lamivudine.html">abacavir, dolutegravir, and lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cdi" href="/cdi/abacavir-dolutegravir-and-lamivudine.html">abacavir, dolutegravir, and lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-ppa" href="/ppa/abacavir-dolutegravir-and-lamivudine.html">Abacavir, Dolutegravir, and Lamivudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-pro" href="/pro/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudinetablets.html">Abacavir, Lamivudine and ZidovudineTablets</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-mtm" href="/mtm/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine.html">abacavir, lamivudine, and zidovudine</a>
<a class="doc-type doc-type-cons" href="/cons/abacavir-lamivudine-and-zidovudine.html">abacavir, lamivudine, and zidovudine</a>
```

but i want the text indside `a` in an array which is

```
A & D topical
A + D Cracked Skin Relief cream
A-200 Lice Treatment....
.............
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a method to convert to a list.

```
public List<String> contents(Elements elements) {
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element element : elements) {
        list.add(element.text());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: If an element exists e.g. `<a href="#"><span class="foo">bar</span></a>` then this will strip out the `span`. I wonder whether that matters.

Comment: OP can adjust if he needs to.  He specified that he wanted "the text".

Comment: 'Text' is ambiguous. But yes, it's an easy fix. Just something to be aware of in case the inputs change.

Comment: Just a note: you could also use the map function: `List<String> list = e.stream().map(element -> element.text()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all of the elements and get the inner HTML:

```
final Elements e = document.select(".doc-type-list li a");
for (final Element elem : e)
{
    System.out.println(elem.html());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the element's own text

`for (Element element : e) {
    System.out.println(element.ownText());
}`